# Android: bend bitmap/image to set as a cylindrical shape

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

Is it possible to bend an image or bitmap, like belows, using android's native graphics library? 
I have found [ImageMagick](https://github.com/tapaulo/Android-ImageMagick) and [JHLabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tvrl.png) image processing libraries, which can be used to achieve this type of effect. But, I don't wish to use those complex library to achieve only this effect.
Is there any other simple ways to do this? Also, i've no experiences in android opengl :(

[image]

Comment: You should probably be able to do this by applying a corresponding matrix to the bitmap - have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean%29 - the challenge will be to define the appropriate matrix.

Comment: @AleksG: Matrices can only encode linear transformations. Bending is a non-linear transformation.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ok, then matrix transform of an image isn't going to work...  Then OpenGL is probably the best bet